# A generalization of the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a uniformly bounded family of independent mean zero random variables. Suppose each $X_n$ has variance $\sigma_n^2$, and that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_n^2 = \infty$. I am trying to prove that

$$Z_n := \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_j^2 }}$$

converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. It seems like the best approach is to reduce it to the ordinary central limit theorem somehow. However, without any further hypotheses on the $X_n$, I do not see a way to get a sequence of identically distributed random variables. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Two observations: 1 If $X_n$ are bounded, the condition $\sigma_n^2<\infty$ seems redundant. 2. check your definition of $Z_n$, as it's written it doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: I have fixed the mistakes.

Comment: Do you know Lindeberg-Feller? Or Lyapunov?

Comment: See, for example, [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30022) on mathoverflow.net.